# Changing Textview color

Tags: android, colors, textview

am trying this code 
am learing this from a tutorial i found online coding speedometer android

```
 String strCurrentSpeed = fmt.toString();
    strCurrentSpeed = strCurrentSpeed.replace(' ', '0');

    String strUnits = "Km/h";
    if (this.useMetricUnits())
    {
      strUnits = "m/s";
    }
    Typeface mytxt = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "DS-DIGIB.TTF");
    TextView txtCurrentSpeed = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txtCurrentSpeed);
    txtCurrentSpeed.setText(strCurrentSpeed + " " + strUnits);
    txtCurrentSpeed.setTypeface(mytxt);

    int speed = Integer.parseInt(strCurrentSpeed + " " );
    if(speed <= 70){
        txtCurrentSpeed.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.backcolor_overspeed));
    }
```

and am getting RunTImeException 
java.lang.NumberFormatException :invalid Int: 000.0

am still new to coding.
thanks for your help

Comment: `<color name="backcolor_overspeed">#FF0000</color>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RunTimeException java.lang.NumberFormatException :invalid Int: 000.0
```

Is caused by:

```
int speed = Integer.parseInt(strCurrentSpeed + " " );
```

or more specifically:

```
Integer.parseInt(strCurrentSpeed + " " )
```

It means that Java does not agree with you that 000.0 is an integer. Since it contains a point, it is no longer an Integer (whole number), but a Float. Use:

```
Float.parseFloat(strCurrentSpeed)
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

this line is your problem

```
 int speed = Integer.parseInt(strCurrentSpeed + " " );
```

there shouldnt be any spaces, the method Integer.parseInt converts a String into a number, providing this string does not have  "non numeric" chars, and is limited to only one . (decimal dot)

because your extra char is a space, you do not see this error displayed...

Comment: i've tried the (strCurrentSpeed) and its still giving me the invalid int 000.0

Comment: try Double.parseDouble instead, there is a dot in the number, it is not an Integer, the definition of an Integer is whole number, no decimal point